# Prove that there exist arbitrarily long sequence of consecutive integers not of the form $x^k$ with $k > 1$. (Assuming that $x \in \mathbb Z$)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not sure how to approach this question exactly, I've thought about assuming that the length of the sequence is finite and bounded above and somehow construct a contradiction.

Any hint on how to approach this question would be great, thanks.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty} [(n+1)^k - n^k].$

Comment: How do you ensure that no numbers between $(n+1)^k$ and $n^k$ is of the form $x^k$

Comment: Assuming that $x\in\mathbb{Z}, ~x < n \implies x^k < n^k.$ Similarly, $x > (n+1) \implies x^k > (n+1)^k.$

Comment: Oh, I see, so you fix $k$, and consider the limit.

Comment: Yes, and rely heavily on the idea that there are no integers $x$ such that $~x> n~$ **and** $~x < (n+1).$

Comment: But is $k$ supposed to be fixed?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $k$ is not supposed to be fixed, I'm trying to understand your answer right now, the limit suggestion wouldn't really work since the only restriction on $k$ is $>1$.

Comment: How are you doing with my answer? You can leave a comment on it if there's something you need help with.

Comment: Are you still here, McBas?

Comment: It's not polite to post a question and then refuse to engage with a posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Any number of the form $4n+2$ can't be a perfect power (because it's divisible by $2$ but not by $4$). Similarly for any number of the forms $9n+3$, $25n+5$, $49n+7$, and so on. So all you have to do is show that for any $m$ there exists $r$ such that $r\equiv2\bmod4$ and $r+1\equiv3\bmod9$ and and and $r+m-1\equiv p_m\bmod{p_m^2}$.